# razor throws an exception while rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a razor statement:

```
@{
    var renderColumn = new Action<OlapReportColumn>(col =>
    {
        if (col.IsSpaned)
        {
            @<th colspan="@col.Columns.Count">@col.Caption</th>;
        }
    });
}
```

Here is a code for render html table's header. So while I trying to call view I get an exception (translated from russian) as:

> an operator can be used only assignment expression, call, increment, decrement and expectations

Here is a razor generated code part with an error:

```
    var renderColumn = new Action<OlapReportColumn>(col =>
    {
        if (col.IsSpaned)
        {


            #line default
            #line hidden
item => new System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult(__razor_template_writer => { // ERROR HERE!

BeginContext(__razor_template_writer, "~/Areas/Report/Views/ReportsOlap/ReportTableGenerator.cshtml", 324, 3, true);
```

Here a part of razor code called `renderColumn`

```
    <table id="reportGrid">
        <thead>    
            <tr>
                @foreach (var h in report.Header)
                {
                    renderColumn(h);
                }
            </tr>
```

What I am doing wrong in here?

Answer (score 1):

The `Action` that you've defined is behaving just like any other method in C#. The line `@<th colspan="@col.Columns.Count">@col.Caption</th>;` is *not* simply output to the output stream; instead the compiler is seeing a statement that it doesn't understand resulting in the error:

> CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

In order to write the `<th colspan="@col.Columns.Count">@col.Caption</th>` to the output stream you can use the [`WriteLiteral`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase.writeliteral%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) method:

```
var renderColumn = new Action<OlapReportColumn>(col =>
{
    WriteLiteral("<th colspan=" + col.Columns.Count + ">" + col.Caption + "</th>");
});
```

Perhaps more idiomatic than that though would be to use a `Func` that returns what you'd like to ouptut and then output that at the call site:

```
var renderColumn = new Func<OlapReportColumn, object>(col =>
{
    return Html.Raw("<th colspan=" + col.Columns.Count + ">" + col.Caption + "</th>");
});
```

The call would then need to be changed very slightly to tell razor that you wish to output the results:

```
@foreach (var h in report.Header)
{
    @(renderColumn(h))
}
```

Going further, there is built-in support for `Func`s of this nature as described in [this blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx/) by Phil Haack. Using this method your call stays the same as the call just above but the `Func` becomes:

```
Func<OlapReportColumn, object> renderColumn2 
    = @<th colspan="@item.Columns.Count">@item.Caption</th>;
```

From Phil Haack's blog

> *Note that the delegate that’s generated is a `Func<T, HelperResult>`. Also, the @item parameter is a special magic parameter.*

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your HTML table header code from this :

```
@<th colspan="@col.Columns.Count">@col.Caption</th>;
```

to this :

```
@:<th colspan="@col.Columns.Count">@col.Caption</th>;
```

Insert that colon `:` immediately after `@` delimeter and check if this works.

Comment: Thats probably because it cant find the `table` tag.